# Anaconda not setting Scripts file when installing

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

After succesfull instalation message from anaconda3 2019.07 installer, I cannot find the scripts file in the installation directory ("C:\Users...\Anaconda3").

I found many fixes to installing anaconda and many of those consist of including the scripts file path to the environment variables path. Then I noticed that I could not find this file whatsoever.

I've been uninstalling and installing it but the "scripts" file seems to not be set during install procedure.

Comment: "*many fixes...consist of including the scripts file path to the environment variables path*" Yes, but such "fixes" are pre-Conda 4.6 and given your Anaconda you have Conda 4.7, so should be using `conda init`, not manipulating `PATH` manually. Unfortunately, you still need to find `conda.exe`. Is there a `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts`? [This seems to be a recurring issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/8460). Personally, I endorse the "Install Miniconda instead" solution. If you need Anaconda, then `conda create -n my_env anaconda`.

Comment: There is no C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts file. I just installed the same release of anaconda3 in my laptop and it worked just fine, but my desktop continues having installation issues. I'll check the miniconda solution, thanks.

Comment: Miniconda3 installation presented the same issues as anaconda3. I attempted to install 32 bit version of anaconda3 (even though both my OS and processor are 64 bits) and it worked just fine for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From the FAQ:

> **In what folder should I install Anaconda on Windows?**
> We recommend installing Anaconda or Miniconda into a directory that contains only
> 7-bit ASCII characters and no spaces, such as C:\anaconda. Do not
> install into paths that contain spaces such as C:\Program Files or
> that include Unicode characters outside the 7-bit ASCII character set.
> This helps ensure correct operation and no errors when using any
> open-source tools in either Python 3 or Python 2 conda environments.

In my case, I reinstalled Miniconda3 in a folder located at a "shorter" path (D:\Miniconda3) and the Scripts folder were created.

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether you have Scripts folder inside anaconda3.

You can set the path to Scripts folder in the "Path" Environment variable inside control panel(Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables) as

C:\Users.....\anaconda3\Scripts

Hope this helps.